# how to create your own custom data types with Validating Type

Tags: vb.net, static, maskedtextbox

[MaskedTextBox.ValidatingType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.validatingtype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_MaskedTextBox_ValidatingType)

If you want to use your own custom data types with **ValidatingType**, you must implement a static Parse method that takes a string as a parameter. This method must be implemented with one or both of the following signatures:

```
public static Object Parse(string)

public static Object Parse(string, IFormatProvider)
```

It is not well described and this code is related to C#.net . What should i do for vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

documents microsoft says:You can use ValidatingType to verify whether the data entered by the user falls within the correct range.

In this example, we want to have a 9-digit code with no spaces and letters:

012345678 --> valid input (But zero will be deleted. We can take the type of string or the ten digits, but do not count the 10 digits.)

999999999 --> valid input

88_88_888 --> invalid input

8888_____ --> invalid input

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs)Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "000-000-000" 'My custom mask 
    Me.MaskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = GetType(myCustomType)   
    Me.ToolTip1.IsBalloon = True
End Sub

Structure myCustomType
    Public code As Integer
    Public Shared Function Parse(s As String) As myCustomType
        s = s.Trim
        If s.Length = 9 Then
            Dim newObject As New myCustomType
            newObject.code = UInt32.Parse(s)
            Return newObject 'Valid
        Else
            Return Nothing 'Invalid
        End If
    End Function
End Structure

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
TypeValidationEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.TypeValidationCompleted
    If (Not e.IsValidInput) Then
        Me.ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Invalid Date"
        Me.ToolTip1.Show("your message", Me.MaskedTextBox1, 0, -20, 5000)
    Else
        ' Now that the type has passed basic type validation, enforce more specific 
        'type rules.        
        'Anything you want to do after the user input is correct. write here...
    End If
End Sub

' Hide the tooltip if the user starts typing again before the five-second 
' display limit on the tooltip expires.
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) 
Handles MaskedTextBox1.KeyDown
    Me.ToolTip1.Hide(Me.MaskedTextBox1)
End Sub
```